# Algorithmic complexity of this nested loop

Tags: algorithm, c++11, time-complexity, big-o

Is it `O(n)` or `O(n*logn)` of the code below:

```
for(int j=n, int sum = 0; j>0 ; j--) 
    for(int k=j; k >0; k--) sum++;
```

List of iterations:

```
j = 5: k = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
j = 4: k = 4, 3, 2, 1,
j = 3: k = 3, 2, 1
j = 2: k = 2, 1
j = 1: k = 1
```

We have 15 iterations in total.
But, if it is `O(n)`, then only 5 iterations must be.

And if it is `O(n*logn)` answer would be only around 11-12 iterations.

Comment: That's not how Big O works. You can't look at the number of iterations for a specific n and determine the algorithmic complexity, you need to analyze the number of iterations for general values of n.

Comment: The world isn't just made of O(n) and O(n Log n) algorithms !

Comment: Hint: what's the area of a triangle ? [Not kidding]

Comment: @YvesDaoust (1/2) * base * height

Comment: @John I believe that Yves Daoust already knows the area of the triangle :)

Comment: @xenteros no no, he's not kidding!... ja ja XD actually I understand how to calculate complexity, as well as what OP is asking, but couldn't understand what the hint (area of a triangle) has to do with code sample....

Comment: Actually it's a triangle which area is n^2/2 and it's the number of operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `O(n^2)`. Why? Well it takes:

[image]

Look, that for `n = 5` the number of calculations i 15 in deed. On the other hand, for `n=100` it will be 5050. Which is far away from `100log100` which is around 460.

According to *Wikipedia*:

> Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity. It is a member of a family of notations invented by Paul Bachmann, Edmund Landau, and others, collectively called Bachmann-Landau notation or asymptotic notation.